# install business intelligence project in vs 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, business-intelligence

How can I install business intelligence project in vs 2008.

I can not option in new project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) is part of the **SQL Server** product - when you install SQL Server 2008 (or 2008 R2), you have the option of installing BIDS.

Comment: So it is not possible to have the actual SQL Server on one machine (a server), and the BIDS on another machine that can connect to the server if needed? (We currently have to RD to the server to create SSIS packages, that is annoying.)

Comment: @GSerg: **sure!** The BIDS is just part of the SQL Server install - so to install it on a second machine, you need to start up the SQL Server installation from the SQL Server disk/.ISO on that second machine, and then install only the BIDS parts from the installer...